# How to do "if" in Linq orderby?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have 2 fields for sorting: Product Name and Price plus 2 options: ascending or descending.

User can specify sort order by setting 2 checkboxes: Price checkbox on or off and ascending checkbox on or off.

How do I code the orderby clause when the sorting order is dynamically set based on settings of the 2 above checkboxes? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build the query by conditionally specifying `OrderBy` clauses:

```
var query = from product in db.Products select product;

if(price.Checked && ascending.Checked)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(product => product.Price);
}
else if(price.Checked && !ascending.Checked)
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(product => product.Price);
}
else if(!price.Checked && ascending.Checked)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(product => product.Name);
}
else
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(product => product.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the ascendingCondition below is based on your code

```
if(ascendingCondition)
{
   ProductCollection.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ThenBy(p => p.Price)
}
else
{
   ProductCollection.OrderByDescending(p => p.Name).ThenByDescending(p => p.Price)
}
```